# BizTalk 2013 R2 Large DB Log File

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

I have this alert on my client staging server :

> Total DB Space Used  for DTA DB "BizTalkDTADb" on Biztalk Server
>   1024619.49 (Large size on DTA db can impact also MsgBox Db performance, check Tables size and if 'DTA Purge and Archive' job is running)
>
> DTA DB DATA File size : 2314 MB
>
> DTA DB LOGFile size : 1022306 MB

My DTA purge JOB is configured to only purge without archive, but even after the purge/shrink LOG file, the size not decrease. Have you an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Info from elsewhere, OP is using an unsupported backup process.  Here's the Answer:

So...**this is not supported and will not work**.  You must use the BackupBizTalkServer job.

Regarding DBA's, the BizTalk Databases and SQL Server are part of the BizTalk product and *must be managed by the BizTalk Administrators*.  I'm going to assume you've never tried to recover your BizTalk Group since there is a distinct possibility that the backups they have been taking are not useful.

Additionally, **you must stop any non-BizTalk maintenance jobs** running against the BizTalk databases.  They are not supported and likely to cause problems.

So, your solution is to stop the custom, unsupported, backup process, then properly configure ALL the BizTalk Agent Jobs, including BackupBizTalk Server.

I fully expect the DBA to object but keep in mind, *they caused this problem by not properly backing up BizTalk Server*.